# 90% of the time, my PC works fine but sometimes it shows nothing on the display

Tags: boot, display, motherboard, gpu

Im 16, I recently built my first PC.

All seemed to be going well at first. Some parts I took from my dads old system and place holders until I can afford newer parts. 90% of the time when I turn it on it works fine but rarely it won't appear on display. All the fans and lights in the system are on but no display, not even BIOS. I am wondering where the root of the issue is and how I can fix it.

A little information about my system:

I have an:

- AMD Ryzen 5 3600
- ASRock B450 Steel Legend
- 16GBb of G.SKILL DDR4-3300MHz
- 650 watt power supply
- NVIDIA Quadro K2200 GPU (5 years old)
- 1TB Ssamsung Sata SSD (also 5 years old)

I suspect the issue is either coming from the motherboard or GPU. While installing the motherboard I did drop a screwdriver on it, which I'm afraid caused some damage, and the GPU is old but works pretty well.

Maybe that caused it, but I guess it could also be something I changed in BIOS, I've been fiddling with it a lot.

Not sure if this is related somehow but I just noticed my case fans all start at different times after I turn on the PC. From right to left (in succession). Additionally, the “Num Lock” LED on my keyboard turns on and stays on, while there is no display

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Reset bios/uefi to standard. Dont run the XMP profile for memory, try using a jedec standard for say 3000Mhz.  If applicable, connect a simple pc speaker to hear any beep codes to help determine whats wrong.

Comment: Thanks ill try all that and get back to you

Comment: So I did all that and nothing changed ik still met with the same problem, I was unable to connect a speaker.

Comment: is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Without any debug leds or an internal speaker te hear error codes, its going to be very hard to determine the error. The problem as you described it, reminded me of the memory problems with first gen ryzen cpu's. Have you tried booting with just one stick of memory ? Even more relaxed speeds (2800Mhz) or timings ? Make sure nothing else is connected to the PC that doesnt *have* to be.

Comment: I see. could I use headphones to hear the error codes?

Comment: @DylanJoyce no, it outputs the sound signals to the systems pins on the motherboard only

Comment: I had a similar case with one motherboard. The issue came from the specific RAM module sitting in the second slot and preventing signals to pass through and BIOS was hanging and RAM check. So I suggest to play with cards and modules you have installed to find the non-working combination.

Comment: Ok, ill try that tomorrow and update you all, thanks so much for your help